warning concerning S3 method in checking new package
I am trying to create a new package. After building the package in Rstudio, I ran
R CMD check (in a terminal) and got the following warning (the only one I got):
summary:
function(object, ...)
summary.rqcan:
function(a, pr, ci, fact, ...)
See section ‘Generic functions and methods’ in the ‘Writing R Extensions’ manual.
When I install the package locally (install.packages("/Users/sportnoy/desktop/rqcanon", repos = NULL,  type = "source"), the functions all run fine on all my tests (including the fact that

summary(a)
properly invokes summary.rqcan(a). How can I fix this? If it isn't fixed, can the package still be uploaded to CRAN?

I hoped not to get any errors or warnings
